# Android - Cross domain requests not allowed after changing the target SDK version

Tags: android, cross-domain

I'm developing an Android app (using PhoneGap), which initially had the 14 version as SDK target, but when I changed it to 16 it didn't allow cross domain requests anymore, is there something else I have to change on the manifest??

This is the message I get in LogCat:

```
E/Web Console(27364): XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myserver. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. at null:1
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that there'll be anything that you can change.
I had a similar issue when moving to ICS because they update the version of WebKit that the browser uses which changes it's behaviour.

Comment: But there must be a way to allow cross domain requests. Anyway, the WebKit version used doesn't depend on the SDK level I used in the application, does it? Doesn't it depend on the Android version of the device? Correct me if I'm wrong, but first I used the SDK 14 and installed the app in a device with Jelly Bean (level 16) and everything went fine. When I used the SDK 16, I got this error, but aren't they using the same WebKit version (the one included in the device)??